# Setting default date for datepicker in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I have implemented moment js for my datepicker in a MVC website but I cant get the default date to work. I just shows 1. january 2015. I want it to show todays date.

Model

```
public class TeamModel
{
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

Controller. I set my start and end date:

```
model.Team = new Team();
model.Team.StartDate = DateTime.Today;
model.Team.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
```

In my View I have the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        moment.lang('da');
        $('#Team_StartDate').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'da',
        format: 'D-MMMM-YYYY',
        showClose: true,
        showClear: true,
        toolbarPlacement: 'top'
    });

        $('#Team_EndDate').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'da',
            format: 'D-MMMM-YYYY',
            showClose: true,
            showClear: true,
            toolbarPlacement: 'top'
    });
    });
</script>
```

and the editorfor

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Team.StartDate, htmlAttributes:
new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Team.StartDate, new {
                @Value = Model.Team.StartDate.ToString(), htmlAttributes = 
new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
model.Team.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

But the date displayed in StartDate is "1-januar-2015" and "31-januar-2015" in EndDate.

Comment: What are the actual values of `Model.Team.StartDate` and `Model.Team.EndDate`? The fact that the end date is exactly 30 days after the start date seems to suggest that there's no something wrong with the interpretation of the date by your picker. Bear in mind that `DateTime.Today`/`DateTime.Now`, are local dates, i.e. server time. If the server's date/time is incorrect, then you're boned. It's generally better to use UTC dates/times and then format into the local time explicitly.

Comment: You don't need the `new { @Value = Model.Team.StartDate.ToString()`,` - the `EditorFor()` method already adds the correct `value` attribute based on the value of your property.